# store an arc in a variable

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics

I have a couple of arcs (circles) That I would like to store in a variable. A rectangle can be stored like this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(float x, float y, width, height);
```

Is their a similar way to store the information required for an arc or path?

Comment: How are you creating the arcs?

Comment: Generally speaking, an arc is a radius and an angle.

Comment: @JoshCaswell CGContextAddArc(...)

Comment: @HotLicks: And an x and a y position. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use UIBezierPath.

From the documentation:

> Paths can define simple shapes such as rectangles, ovals, and arcs or
>   they can define complex polygons that incorporate a mixture of
>   straight and curved line segments.

You can, for example, draw an oval by doing the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];

    [path stroke];
}
```

Comment: the NSBezierPath doesnt exist in the auto suggestion. But the UIBezierPath do but I cant use that with quartz right?

Comment: Are you writing an iOS or OS X application? How were you planning on drawing your rectangle?

Comment: IOS. I have a circle that are drawn when a UIButton is pressed. And in the same method I want another circle to be drawn when the first one has been drawn. Thats why I thought creating a variable to start with.

Comment: UIBezierPath can be used with Quartz. For CG functions, you can get the .CGPath property out of it.

Comment: But in your example, you create an oval in a rect. Isn't it a way to draw a "real" circle. Like CGContextAddArc(...)

Comment: A circle is an oval drawn in a square rectangle. There is nothing more or less real about using the CGContext functions over UIBezierPath. UIBezierPath is a wrapper around those lower level CG functions.

Answer (score 1):

The fast/light way in most cases would be to create a `CGPath` representing the arcs (see also `CGMutablePath`). You can then draw the path into a `CGContext`.

Alternatively, you could pack up the parameters you will be passing to `CGContextAddArc`. For example:

```
@interface MONArc : NSObject

@interface (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat x;
@interface (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat y;
@interface (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat radius;
@interface (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat startAngle;
@interface (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat endAngle;
@interface (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) int clockwise;

@end
```

Then save a few of those in an `NSArray` and apply them in order when rendering.